# how to convert date string in 2014-05-28T10:51:40.3056+01:00 to dd-mmm-yyyy format in ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, date

I'm very new to this ios. I want to convert 2014-05-28T10:51:40.3056+01:00 to 28-may-2014.But I'm getting null. please help me .

```
//here dateString is 2014-05-28T10:51:40.3056+01:00
NSString * dateString= [dict objectForKey:@"created_date"];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
[df setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];

NSDate *inputDate = [df dateFromString: dateString];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yy"];

NSString *    inputValue = [df stringFromDate:inputDate];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSString * dateString = @"2014-05-28T10:51:40.3056+01:00";

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    [df setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ"];

    NSDate *inputDate = [df dateFromString: dateString];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yy"]; //  [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];

    NSString *inputValue = [df stringFromDate:inputDate];
```

**Output:** 28-May-14

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have been facing the same issue but then I split the Date string from . because it's not take the formate

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
            if ([dateFormat dateFromString:[[value componentsSeparatedByString: @"-"] objectAtIndex:0]] == nil) {
                value = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[value componentsSeparatedByString: @"-"] objectAtIndex:0]];
            } else {
                value = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[value componentsSeparatedByString: @"."] objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
```